# Counting Combination Pairs in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, countif

Alright, I have a spreadsheet that looks like this in the "B" column:

1. AAA
2. BBB
3. BBB
4. AAA
5. BBB
6. CCC
7. DDD
8. BBB
9. AAA
10. BBB
11. CCC

What I need to do is to count how many times "BBB" directly follows "AAA" (In this example 3 times)

Ive tried multiple things with =SumProduct like =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(K6:K10,{"AAA","BBB"})) but that returns the product of all "AAA's" and "BBB's" instead of just the number of AAA & BBB pairs. The best I could do is to use =countifs() but I cant see a way to do a forward lookup like =countifs("B:B","AAA","B+1:B+1","BBB")

Also, I should mention, I was hoping to use this somewhere in the formula "Table13[[#All],[Radio State]]." That way the formula would grow and shrink depending on the size of the table.

Does anyone happen to know if its possible to do this?

Thanks Guys,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can 'offset' the range by a bit like this:

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A10, "AAA", A2:A11, "BBB")
```

You can change the range accordingly.

---

With a table:

```
=COUNTIFS(Table13[[#All],[Radio State]],"AAA",OFFSET(Table13[[#All],[Radio State]],1,0),"BBB")
```

Comment: yeah I just noticed that too... is there are way to include this bit in the formula "Table13[[#All],[Radio State]]" -  that way the formula would grow and shrink with the table? The table is automated and I have no idea what the ending row will be, it could be 10 or 10,000.

Comment: @Nefarii Sure, I just tried an edited formula and it seems to be working. Added it to my answer.